# How do you package a tree-sitter grammar for consumption?

Tags: node-modules, treesitter

Say you want to write a program that consumes a tree-sitter grammar you've written, using the [node-tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter/node-tree-sitter) package. How do you package the grammar you've written for consumption? What is the minimal set of files that must be included in the node module? In the [package.json file of the javascript module](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-javascript/blob/master/package.json) there's a section specific to tree-sitter, is it important to fill that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that section of the `package.json` is only used by the `tree-sitter` CLI tool, when running `tree-sitter parse` or `tree-sitter highlight`. It is described [here](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/syntax-highlighting#language-configuration).

To use a Tree-sitter grammar with `node-tree-sitter`, you just need to ensure that the `nan` module is included in the `dependencies` of your package.json. The `tree-sitter generate` command will generate the other files that are needed for exposing the code to Node.js: `binding.gyp` and `src/binding.cc`. If you want to publish your module to npmjs.com, you can do that with the [usual commands](https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry) (e.g. `npm publish`).

Comment: I will also add here that if you just want to import your grammar module locally without publishing it, you have to re-run `npm install` in your grammar directory after every change to the grammar.